# String formatting float in python

Tags: python, string, directory, string-formatting, mkdir

Does someone know why `lambdaPathlet`is cut of?

```
lambdaPathlet=0.001
os.mkdir(wk_dir+"/"+dir_name+"_"'%d'%(lambdaPathlet,)+"_"'%d'%(resolution,)+"x"'%d'%(resolution,))
```

The folder i get is labeled `Room4_0_40x40`but should be named `Room4_0.001_40x40` How can i fix it?

Comment: This isn't really specific to `mkdir`, but rather percent-style string formatting. `"%d" % 0.001` will give you `'0'` regardless of whether it's inside a mkdir call.

Comment: true, thank you i will edit my post. anyways do you know how to fix it?

Comment: try with os.mkdir(wk_dir + "/" + dir_name + "_%s_%dx%d" % (lambdaPathlet, resolution, resolution))

Comment: that works perfectly fine, thank you @Roomm

Comment: you should use `os.path.join` for this

Answer (score 0):

os.mkdir(wk_dir+"/"+dir_name+"*"'%0.3f'%(lambdaPathlet,)+"*"'%d'%(resolution,)+"x"'%d'%(resolution,))